# Javascript: Variable as While Condition

Tags: javascript, variables, while-loop, conditional-statements

I would like to specify the while's condition as a variable, something like:

```
function doWhile(condition){
    while(condition){
       number++;
    }
    alert(number);
}

var number = 1;
doWhile(number < 10);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is using functions.

```
function doWhile(condition, action, undefined) {
    var current = undefined;
    // call your condition with the current value
    while(condition(current)) {
        // do something with the current value then update it
        current = action(current);
    }
    return result;
}

var number = doWhile(function condition(number) {
    // if the current value has no value yet continue
    // if the current value is less than 10
    return number === undefined || number < 10;
}, function action(number) {
    // if the number has no value set it to 0
    if (number === undefined) {
         number = 0;
    }
    // increase it
    return ++number;
});
console.log(number);
```

Comment: What, you don't want to run `eval()` in a loop? ;o) +1

Comment: @patrick_dw I was tempted. But I decided to do it properly. Besides if I show him the eval solution, he'll go "thats easier/nicer I'll just use that. What do you mean eval is bad? eval is fine!"

Comment: @Raynos: I saw that *exact* situation earlier this year, but with someone giving a solution using `with`. It took only a few minutes for OP to break his code, but was *convinced* that `with` was the solution anyway.

Comment: Well, it works, but I don't really understand what's going on :S, `return number === undefined || number < 10;` Why do I need the `number === undefined` part from here?

Comment: @CIRK the first call is `undefined`. You can initialize `result = 0` if you want. But then it defaults to 0 instead of `undefined` and wouldn't work nicely with strings or arrays. I can imagine this looking alien if your not used to passing first class functions around like this.

Comment: @Raynos , I didn't even know that I can pass parameters to functions when I call it in this way `var number = doWhile(par, par2);` I was always doing it in this way : `var number = function(){ doWhile(par, par2); };` So now I'm a bit confused :)) and what's the `++number`? Shouldn't this be `number++`, there are lots of new stuff for me in your answer.. :-)

Comment: @CIRK `++number` increments the number first then returns it. `number++` returns the number then increments.